# Jrpc calls through jmeter

Tags: jmeter, grpc

I wanted to make a grpc calls through jmeter .Have done some searches but not getting the proper doc or site.

Would like to know if it is possible to make grpc calls through jmeter.
Also do we have some example doc/site for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GRPC has [Java API](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/quickstart/) so you can generate client code (or reuse your application code if it's in Java) and implement the business use cases using [JSR223 Samplers and Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) language

Unfortunately the absolute maximum of information I can provide as the client code will be specific to your application so no one will be able to help unless you want to share the source code of your app which is highly unlikely to happen.

You may also take a look at [jmeter-grpc-plugin](https://github.com/zalopay-oss/jmeter-grpc-plugin) (you will still have to write the code) and [Client-side streaming RPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/basics/#client-side-streaming-rpc) example